# How to retrieve all highlighted words in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Div with only text components and some text have been highlighted with background color rgb(255,255,0).

What I want to do is to fetch whatever is highlighted with color rgb(255,255,0) in this div and convert them into an array of string using javascript.

Here's the html code:

```
<html><head>
 </head>

    <body class="body">
        <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
        2009 BMW for $5,800.00
        <br>
        Manheim Auto-Assign on run 3
        <br><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">
        Condition</span> and <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Documentation</span> issues
        <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
        Estimated Gross Profit of $15.00
        <br>
        Estimated Margin Variance of -42%
        <br>
        <br>
        Offer of $5,775.00
        <br>
        Current Offer Variance of $825.00

</body></html>
```

Now from this html, i want to retrieve the text `Condition` and `Documentation` since they are the highlighted words, and store them in a array.
Can anyone help in how to do this in javascipt?

Comment: Can you help us help you by posting your code so far and explaining what didn't work?

Comment: May you provide the text?

Comment: may be he wants to us to write a JS code

Comment: I have edited my question for clear understanding of what i want to do. If anyone have the js code for how to do this it would be really helpful.

Comment: Are they always wrapped with a span element? Or could they vary, but have a style attribute set to `#ffff00`? For instance, `<p style="rgb(255,255,0)">` ?

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. : Yes the highlighted words would always be wrapped in a span with background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian This question is asking about getting text contained in elements with a certain kind of style attribute value, not about selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dupivuzu/7/edit?html,console,output)

```
var hili = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var hiliArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<hili.length; i++){
  var that = hili[i];
  var bg = that.style.backgroundColor.replace(/ /g,'');
  if (bg=="rgb(255,255,0)"){
    var purifiedText = that.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    hiliArray.push(purifiedText);
  }
}

console.log(hiliArray);// ["Condition","Documentation"]
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use the following selector to target the spans containing your text:

```
$.("[style~='(255,255,0)']")
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

EDIT: Changed selector target from 'ffff00' to '(255,255,0)'